# How do I use functions in my php code?

Tags: php, function

I'm learning about functions in my programming class and no matter what I do I just cant get this to work. Here is the problem that needs fixing:

What's wrong here?

The **`getWage()`** function is supposed to calculate overtime (time and a half) for any hours worked above 40. The function is working just fine but when we send the **`$hoursWorked`** and **`$hourlyWage`** from THIS program the function does not calculate the overtime as time and a half!

Can you fix it? The wage should be **`$605.63`** not **`$573.75`**

Here is my function:

```
<?php

function getWage($hourlyWage, $hoursWorked) {
    if ($hoursWorked <= 40)
        return round(($hourlyWage * $hoursWorked), 2);
    else
        return round((($hourlyWage * 40) +
                ($hourlyWage * 1.5 * ($hoursWorked - 40))), 2);
}
?>
```

and here is where I try to call it to my program:

```
<?php

include("incWageFunctions.php");

$hourlyWage = 12.75;
$hoursWorked = 45;
$wage = getWage($hoursWorked, $hourlyWage);

print("<p>Your hourly wage is $$hourlyWage and you worked
        $hoursWorked hours.</p>");
print("<p>Your wages are $$wage.</p>");
?>
```

Its not calculating the overtime no matter what... Where am I going wrong?! Also, how would you call multiple functions to the same program to calculate different things? Can I just call it with the name after the include statement? Or do I have to have it written out with the { } like my first function in this question??

Comment: Post `incWageFunctions.php` too.

Comment: I did, I had to edit it real quick... Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interchanged `$hoursWorked` and `$hourlyWage`

Change `$wage = getWage($hoursWorked, $hourlyWage);`

To `$wage = getWage($hourlyWage, $hoursWorked);`

Comment: OH MY Goodness! How did I miss that?! Gah! Thank you so so much! Now, how would I call multiple functions into the same program file?

Comment: Inlude it like what you did in `incWageFunctions.php` or place your functions there. Then you can call it like `getWage()`.

Comment: When I try that I get this error:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '{' in F:\xampplite\htdocs\Webtech\coursework\Chapter13\Modify1.php on line 36

Comment: <?php
 
 include("incWageFunctions");
 

  $hoursWorked = $_POST['hoursWorked'];
  $hourlyWage = $_POST['hourlyWage'];
  
   $hoursWorked =  function getStartingWage();

   $hourlyWage = function getWage($hourlyWage, $hoursWorked);
  
  $bonus = function getBonus($wage);

  print("<p>Your hourly wage is $$hourlyWage and you worked
  $hoursWorked hours.</p>");
  print("<p>Your wages are $$wage.</p>");
  print("<p>Your bonus is $$bonus.</p>");
 ?>

Comment: Do not do this `$hoursWorked = function getStartingWage()`. It should be like this `$hoursWorked  = getStartingWage()`. Don't include the function word when calling functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117547/discussion-between-sylvia585-and-stephan-sutter).

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the arguments. In php-file you have coded:

```
$wage = getWage($hoursWorked, $hourlyWage);
```

However, in incWageFunctions.php you have written:

```
function getWage($hourlyWage, $hoursWorked)
```